# React Native (expo) error function .then .catch (why am I receiving TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I have implemented the following function.

```
  async function login(){
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword (auth, email, input)
      .then(value=>{
      console.log('login ok')
      navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{name:'Home'}]
      })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
    })
  };
```

It throws the following error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [{
              name: 'Home'
            }]
          }).catch')
```

The code is doing what it is supposed to do but I still receive the above error.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
const yourScreen=({navigation})=>{//<-- that's what you need 

//...
 async function login(){
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword (auth, email, input)
      .then(value=>{
      console.log('login ok')
      navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{name:'Home'}]
      })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
    })
  };
//...


}

export default yourScreen;
```

**OR**

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
const yourScreen=()=>{
const navigation = useNavigation();//<-----
//...
```